# Consolidating many VirtualHosts into one block, is this a job for SetEnvIf?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-rewrite

**Edit** I think what I need here is `SetEnvIf`

I'm attempting to consolidate all of my port-80 VirtualHosts into one block for convenience, but I'm struggling with the final piece of the puzzle.

All port 80 vhosts accept a `www` and `non-www` connection to `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`. All other requests 301 to https://example.com/ - no www.

I think I need to turn `%{HTTP_HOST}` into a *Define*able variable *minus the possible "www"*, e.g. `${SITE}`.

Or maybe there's a better way?

This is where I'm at so far:

```
<VirtualHost ${IP1}:80>
    Define SITE hmmm
    ServerName example-1.com
    ServerAlias www.example-1.com
    ServerAlias example-2.com
    ServerAlias www.example-2.com
    # And so on... 25 vhosts
    DocumentRoot /home/user/htdocs/${SITE}

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/
    RewriteRule ^ https://${SITE}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

    <Directory /home/user/htdocs/${SITE}>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think what I need here is SetEnvIf

But, AFAIK, you cannot use *environment* variables in the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` directives. (And you can't `Define` variables to a calculated/dynamic string using a regex.)

> ```
> DocumentRoot /home/user/htdocs/${SITE}
>
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/
> RewriteRule ^ https://${SITE}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
>
> <Directory /home/user/htdocs/${SITE}>
> ```

You could instead define a `VirtualDocumentRoot` and use an appropriate regex in the mod_rewrite directives and `<DirectoryMatch>` container.

For example, assuming all your domains are of the form `<name>.<tld>` then try the following instead of the above subset of directives:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/home/user/htdocs/%-2.0.%-1.0"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

<DirectoryMatch "/home/user/htdocs/[^.]+\.com">
```

The `%-2.0.%-1.0` part of the `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive captures the domain name and TLD (the last 2 parts) from the requested hostname. Importantly, this excludes an optional www subdomain (3rd part from the right).

The `%1` backreference in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string references the part of the hostname less the optional `www.` prefix (subdomain) captured in the preceding *CondPattern*. (This also excludes the trailing dot in the case of a FQDN.)

The `<DirectoryMatch>` directive allows access to any directory that is of the form `/home/user/htdocs/<example>.com`.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch